# Do the characters on Mystery Science Theater 3000 know that they are on a TV show?

Tags: mystery-science-theater-3000

I saw a behind-the-scenes special of *Mystery Science Theater 3000* where Joel Hogsdon said that the original premise of the show was that Joel was running a "pirate TV station" or something that would hack into airwaves to show what he wanted. While the premise didn't last, I'm wondering if the idea that Joel and the other characters knew they were on a TV show stuck into final version of the show.

The most suggestive evidence of this is the "commercial sign" that comes on every once in a while. It's not clear to me if that means that the characters know they are on a TV show or if there is something more convoluted going on, like it is part of the mad scientists' schemes to make money.

Do the characters actually know they are on a TV show? Is there any episode where they say that they are?

Comment: And yes, I know it's just a show and I should really just relax. Still, I'd like to know if this was ever stated in the show's history, especially since it has been stated out-of-universe that originally it was.